# Series convergence test $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n-(-1)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to determine the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n-(-1)^n}$.

My approach to this question:
I tried the root test so far.
We know that $2^x>0~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, hence $\left|2^{-n-(-1)^n}\right|=2^{-n-(-1)^n}$ (I'm not so sure of this step.)
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{2^{-n-(-1)^n}}&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 2^{\frac{-n-(-1)^n}{n}}
\\&=2^{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-n-(-1)^n}{n}}
\\&=2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Because $\frac{1}{2}<1$, therefore $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n-(-1)^n}$ converges absolutely.

Someone please check my algebra.

**Edit:** I wanted to test for absolute / conditional convergence.
Corrected typos.

Comment: This looks good.

Also: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+2%5E(-n-(-1)%5En)

Comment: @Prototank Thanks. So this statement holds? ($2^x>0$, hence $\left|2^{-n-(-1)^n}\right|=2^{-n-(-1)^n}$.)

Comment: As a sidenote: If you want you can evaluate the sum explicitly by splitting the sum into two sums, one consisting of all the odd $n$ and one with all the even $n$. These sums are just normal geometrical series.

Comment: @tooooony, your initial remark $2^x>0$ is true for all real $x$.

Comment: You can always just note that $0<2^{-n-(-1)^n}\leq 2^{-(n-1)}.$

Comment: Just for fun. 

We see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n-(-1)^n} =&\ \sum_{\text{even}} 2^{-n-(-1)^n}+\sum_{\text{odd}} 2^{-n-(-1)^n}\\
=&\ \sum^\infty_{k=1}2^{-2k-1}+\sum^\infty_{k=0} 2^{-2k}\\
=&\ \frac{1}{6}+\frac{4}{3} = \frac{3}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is good.  Easier is just to say $0 \lt 2^{-n-(-1)^n} \le 2^{-n+1}$ so
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n-(-1)^n}\le \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n+1}$$
which is a geometric series that we know converges, so the original series converges by the comparison test.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I can test absolute convergence in this case?

Comment: Yes, you have absolute convergence because all the terms are positive.  When they are convergence and absolute convergence are equivalent.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, missed that point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to just compute the powers: $$\begin{array}{c|rr}n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\ldots\\\hline-n-(-1)^n&0&-3&-2&-5&-4&-7&-6&-9&-8&-11&\ldots\end{array}$$
So $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n-(-1)^{n}}=-\frac12+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k}=-\frac12+\frac{1}{1-\frac12}=1.5$$

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n-(-1)^n}
$

Sum to $2m$ terms:

$\begin{array}\\
s(2m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2m}2^{-n-(-1)^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left(2^{-(2n-1)+1}+2^{-2n-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left(2^{-2n+2}+2^{-2n-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}2^{-2n}\left(2^{2}+2^{-1}\right)\\
&=\frac92\sum_{n=1}^{m}2^{-2n}\\
&=\frac92\sum_{n=1}^{m}4^{-n}\\
&=\frac92\dfrac{4^{-1}-4^{-n-1}}{1-1/4}\\
&=\frac92\dfrac{1-4^{-n}}{3}\\
&=\frac32(1-4^{-n})\\
&\to \frac32
\qquad\text{since all terms }\to 0\\
\end{array}
$